# Android Studio Terminal crashes on git commit

Tags: git, android-studio, windows-7

I am using Android Studio, Version 1.4.1. Since the beginning of using Android Studio(I think I use it from Version 1.1. and update regurarly) I have problems with the terminal when I am using git in it. Often the terminal crashes when I am just typing in a commit message after calling

```
git commit -a
```

Then there is a file created called

.git/index.lock

After restarting the crashed terminal I have to delete that file. Furthermore I have to delete

```
.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp
.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

in order to continue working with git. Permission on

```
.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp
```

is always denied because vim or nano still have this file open. That is terribly disturbing and slowing down working on the project.

How can I avoid the crashies? I am using Android Studio on Windows 7. I cannot change to another operating system due to IT standards within the company.